# How is stockholder information shared?

Tags: stocks, regulation

Given that I received in the past invitations to annual stockholder meetings I assume my broker is sharing the required information (name and address) with the public company. I have the following questions:

- What information and when is sent from the broker to the company (is this regulated somehow)?
- Can my broker share that information with other third-parties?
- Can public companies further share that information with third-parties? If yes, which ones? Are there any restrictions?

Comment: (In US) I have several times received notices of class-action settlements involving stocks I held and/or transacted during specified periods at a broker. I _believe_ the contact info is actually obtained by the issuer and turned over to the settlement administrator, but haven't confirmed. And it may matter that these notices are done by order of a court with jurisdiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Registered shareholders bought  or were issued shares directly from the company. They are  listed  as "shareholders of record" on the company register which is managed by the company's transfer agent who handles purchase or issuance of shares, dividend payments, transfer or sale of  shares.

Beneficial shareholders own the shares which are are not  registered under the holder's name  and are held in "street name"  by a broker.  By default, these are non-objecting beneficial owners (NOBO) meaning that  their name, share position and address are shared with the companies they've invested in.

You can notify your broker that you want to be an objecting beneficial owner (OBO) in order opt out and  have  this information withheld.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. Do you have any idea whether this information can be shared with other parties, other than the company itself ?

Comment: Sorry but I have  no idea whether this information can be shared with other parties.